# Why does a Lazarus form look 'incorrectly different' on Windows

Tags: window, ubuntu-12.04, lazarus

I create my programs on Ubuntu 12.04 and compile them on Windows (when necessary).

Recently I noticed that my Lazarus projects look different on Ubuntu and Windows. The problem is on Windows XP, 7 and 8. I'm not sure if Vista looks the same.

For example, group boxes containing radio buttons look shrunk in height, thus hiding parts of the components.

Now I have to edit this forms on Windows before compiling for those platforms. What's worse is that when I bring these project back to Ubuntu, the forms looks unnecessarily stretched out (in height).

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is easily to check if the controls themselves have the same height(just query their left and top properties and dump it in a memo or log for verification)

If that is ok, it is probably the font. Default fonts are subject to themes, and sometimes readability/disability settings.

Comment: Thanks Marco... I just open the Ubuntu project 'as is' on Windows, then hit F9. So should I still find the coordinates/sizes change? Of course it could be something to do with the font. Very possible. If I'm not mistaken, I only notice this issue with group boxes (and their contents).

Comment: It was meant as by way of analysis what was happening. I don't know myself.

Answer (score 0):

Consistent cross-platform look is not a trivial task and does not come at no-cost.

Read http://wiki.freepascal.org/Autosize_/_Layout, especially the part that can scale controls on your form depending on the font size that the end user has configured in the Control Panels

Read few chapters from Google: "windows dpi aware applications"